# How to setup Spring Security's Authorization Config for Method Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

It is [Spring Security's recommendation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_ensure_that_all_requests_have_defined_authorization_rules) to deny all requests with missing authorization rules by default:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .filterSecurityInterceptorOncePerRequest(true)
        .mvcMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("APP")
        // ...
        .anyRequest().denyAll()
    )
    // ...
```

Now let's apply this to a simple real-world example.
**The goal is to define 3 endpoints with different access permissions:**

1. "/": homepage, everyone can access
2. "/login": only anonymous users can access
3. "/private": only logged in users with the authority "ROLE_USER" can access

All other pages should automatically be considered as not allowed as long as no explicit permission has been set via annotation at the endpoint method.

The controller therefore looks as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping
    public String index() { return "index"; }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    @PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")
    public String login() { return "login"; }

    @GetMapping("/private")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    public String secrets() { return "private"; }
}
```

According to Spring Security's suggestion, the WebSecurityConfig looks like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain mainFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .authorizeHttpRequestsauthorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().denyAll())
            // ...
}
```

This configuration should declare all endpoints as restricted by default and since method declarations have a higher precedence, permissions on the methods should override accordingly.

**But that is not what happens. With this approach, all endpoints are forbidden and the method annotations are not considered.**

The following customization of the authorization config object respects the method annotations but ignores denyall():

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain mainFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequestsauthorize -> authorize
            .mvcMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().denyAll())
        // ...
}
```

What sense does it make if you have to give permissions both in the filterchain and on the method itself, without the possibility to declare new endpoints as forbidden by default? With this approach, any new endpoint that is not explicitly restricted on method level is completely open to any user.

### So my question is:

How do I configure the SecurityFilterChain in a way that all endpoints, and thus also all new endpoints, are automatically considered as forbidden, and access is exclusively set via method annotations?

Many thanks to all of you who can help to clarify the situation

Comment: *According to Spring Security's suggestion, the WebSecurityConfig looks like this:* That's not the recommendation! The recommendation is: *Ensure that all requests have defined authorization rules* You didn't do that. you have to list all endpoints in your web security configuration, which should be accessed.

Comment: And if I do so, what is the mehod security then for? Just cosmetics? If I have hundreds of endpoints, I'll have to name every endpoint explicitly in the filterchain? That can't be the way to go. Btw: the requests have authorization rules, but they are set on method-level (index left aside).

Comment: You could use wildcards. And yes, that's the way to go. Also it is not recommended to use method security in frontend and REST API, it is made for business services. `denyAll` is just a fallback, if you forget one URL. That's the last part of the recommendation.

Comment: Ok, so I'll have to cover all endpoints within the filterchain, and can then further restrict access on method level. That seems a little bit odd to me, but when this is the convenient way to do, I'll have to obey^^. Why can't I have method security for both mvc and api?

Comment: *Why can't I have method security for both mvc and api?* Technically you could, but it was not made for. But I don't really know the reason. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html *Spring Security has improved support substantially for adding security to your service layer methods.*

Comment: Well, so if there is no decent reason mentioned by Spring Security I will try to get the following done : I will permitAll() in filterchain, go with method security `@PreAuthorize` annotation for restrictions and try to setup an AuthorizationManager which makes finally access decision on whether the requested endoint is annotated with PreAuthorize which leads to according access or not which leads to deny. Not the way Spring Security may be build for, but this would keep the filterchain clean and outsources access logic to the enpoint implementations with forbidding all non-annotated endpoints

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. By now I have this:  .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)
        .requestMatchers("/", "/login*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().denyAll()) That does not allow accessing non pre-authorised controllers (access denied), the pre-authorised are accessible, only that, I noticed that a controller which gets accessed through AJAX (although pre-authorised), still gets an access denied error.

Comment: That's where I am trying to resolve such issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75698804/how-to-deny-access-to-controllers-which-have-no-preauthorize-annotation