# How to deny access to controllers which have no PreAuthorize annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, access-denied, java-17

I've got here Spring Boot Web application.

It was upgraded to the following set-up:

- Java 17
- Spring Boot 3.0.4
- Spring Security 6.0.2
- Jetty 11 server

When I start the application up, I get this line on the console:

> Running with Spring Boot v3.0.4, Spring v6.0.6

I am having issues with Spring Security configuration.

Under **`application.properties`** I have this statement:

```
spring.security.filter.dispatcher-types=request,async,error,forward,include
```

I'm following this Spring Boot migration guide:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8.0/migration/servlet/authorization.html

The security configuration Java file comes next.

```java
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER)
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecConfiguration {

    private final HouseUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private final HouseShiftConfiguration dashShiftConfig;

    private final DBI dbi;
    private final AuditLogService auditLogService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomSecurityconfiguration customSecurityConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    public SecConfiguration(HouseUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService, DBI dbi, HouseShiftConfiguration dashShiftConfig, AuditLogService auditLogService) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.dbi = dbi;
        this.dashShiftConfig = dashShiftConfig;
        this.auditLogService = auditLogService;
    }

    @Bean
    public HouseRedirectAuthenticationSuccessHandler houseRedirectAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new HouseRedirectAuthenticationSuccessHandler(dbi);
    }
  
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfiguration) throws Exception {
       return authConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        HttpSessionRequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
        requestCache.setMatchingRequestParameterName("continue");

        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler csrfRequestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        csrfRequestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");// set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on

        XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler xorCsrfRequestHandler = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        xorCsrfRequestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");// set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
        
        //csrf white list, when you don't want to use csrf, put your url here.
        String[] csrfWhiteList = {
                "/emailSender/**"
        };

        http
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(csrfRequestHandler)
            )
            .csrf((xorCsrf) -> xorCsrf
                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(xorCsrfRequestHandler)
            )
            .csrf()
                .ignoringRequestMatchers(csrfWhiteList) 
                .and() 
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(dashShiftConfig.tokenBasedRememberMeServicesCore())
                .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD/*, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.REQUEST*/).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/accessDenied", "/security_check", "/img/*", "/js/*", "/css/*", "/?*", "/", "/login*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().denyAll())           
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/security_check")
                .failureUrl("/?r=fail")
                .failureHandler(HouseAuthFailureHandler())
                .successHandler(HouseRedirectAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .and()    
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutHandler())
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","rm")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/?r=invalidSessionUrlLogin")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());

        http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "ALLOW-FROM https://www.secure-service.com"));

        http
            .headers()
                .xssProtection(xssProtection -> xssProtection.headerValue(XXssProtectionHeaderWriter.HeaderValue.ENABLED_MODE_BLOCK))
                .contentSecurityPolicy("form-action 'self'");

        http
            .sessionManagement((sessions) -> sessions
                .requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy(false)
            )
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                .expiredUrl("/?r=sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin");
      
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
         
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.customUserDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(customSecurityConfiguration.passwordEncoder());
     
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

**The guide says this:**

> It’s recommended that Spring Security secure all dispatch types. As such, in 6.0, Spring Security changes this default.
> So, finally, change your authorization rules to filter all dispatcher types.

When I keep the configuration like this:

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/accessDenied", "/security_check", "/img/*", "/js/*", "/css/*", "/?*", "/", "/login*").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().denyAll())
```

I cannot access Spring controllers which do have the `@PreAuthorize()` rule, I get **Access Denied.**

**So, what I want to achieve here is:**

- to allow accessing only those Spring controllers which have the `@PreAuthorize()` constraint set,
- if the controller does not have the `@PreAuthorize()` constraint, deny access to it,
- to allow accessing some controllers (such as CRONs), by invoking them from outside (e.g., from Plesk),
- to understand how each dispatcher type controls the Web app: **`request,async,error,forward,include`**

--------------- Updates on 15/03/2023 --------------

[image]

Comment: Web security is executed first. Method security is executed second. So you have to open all endpoint in web security which should secured by `@PreAuthorize()`.

Comment: @dur In Spring Boot context, I assume that by Web Security you are referring to authentication, overall. When Method Security, @PreAuthorize() annotation, that is authorisation. I wrote already, under the whole post, that if I keep the ...denyAll() (as per the Spring Boot migration guide), "I cannot access Spring controllers which do have the @PreAuthorize() rule, I get Access Denied." N.B., some controllers I cannot access only. By the way, when on older version of the Boot (i.e., v2.*) I could access them.

Comment: @dur Can this be happening because of the wrong permitted DispatcherTypes, under my configuration? N.B., there is a list of dispatcher types to deal with.

Comment: Ok, then I didn't understand your question. Sorry. If you already has all endpoints open (`permitAll` or `authenticated`) , which you are checking with `@PreAuthorize()` then it should work.

Comment: To find your problem it is the best to add Spring Security DEBUG logs. Therefore, you have to change your log configuration.

Comment: Is it due to the fact that you have configured `dispatcherTypeMatchers` to just `DispatcherType.FORWARD` which would mean it will be applied on subsequent requests but not your first request of type `DispatcherType.REQUEST`?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your problem, Spring Security handles authorization in two steps:

1. Within the `SecurityFilterChain` Spring will check whether this specifically filter chain is generaly responsible for the request. Therefore, it will first inspect an optional specified `http.securityMatchers(matchers -> ...)` with which you can prefilter some general routes. Let's say, you wanna have a FilterChain for `api` calls only, this is the way to select all this calls and drag them into this filter chain. Now your're inside the filter chain and Spring will look for a permission. **Here you have to explicitly allow each route within the filter chain**. You can generalize routes with wildcards, but there is no way to omit giving this permission explicitly. By default, Spring Security 6 will apply `denyAll()` for all routes which haven't been set up. This was one of the many changes which were made in the update from 5.x to 6.x.
2. Only when the check of the first step has been successful and the route is permitted, then you can optionally fine grain the safety with method security. Annotations like `PreAuthorize`, `PostAuthorize` and others won't be computed unless the filter chain will find a valid permission in step one. This second step is completely optional, but step one is mandatory.

So this won't work since you don't give permission to any business routes at all:

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/accessDenied", "/security_check", "/img/*", "/js/*", "/css/*", "/?*", "/", "/login*").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().denyAll()
```

You have to set it up somewhat like that:

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/accessDenied", "/security_check", "/img/*", "/js/*", "/css/*", "/?*", "/", "/login*").permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/routes_to_restrict_completely_depending_on_method_security/**").permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/routes_to_restrict_additionally_by_method_security/**")..authenticated()
    .anyRequest().denyAll()
```

The above in mind, your request might not work the way you thought:

> if the controller does not have the @PreAuthorize() constraint, deny access to it,

There might be a way to achieve that behavior, when you first allow the dedicated routes (or all routes in general) and then, in a final step, the `AuthorizationFilter` would come into play. But to be honest, I haven't figured it out yet by myself how to do this with Spring Security 6.